# WPF Fluent Ribbon KeyTip shortcuts not firing commands

Tags: wpf, command, keyboard-shortcuts, fluent-ribbon

I'm using the Fluent `Ribbon`. I'm trying to get the `KeyTip`s working. It works fine for navigation, as I can navigate about between tabs and everything displays correctly. My problem is nothing happens when i finally try to run a command. Take the button below. I can navigate to it by pressing <kbd>ALT -> F</kbd>, when I then press <kbd>C</kbd> nothing happens except it removes the `KeyTip tooltip`. It do not run the actual command. It works fine if I simply click the button. XAML example below of how I bind my command.

```
<Fluent:Button Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"
               Fluent:KeyTip.Keys="C"
               Header="Close" />
```

Is there some special way i need to setup the commands when using KeyTip's?

I've tried the sample that comes with the Fluent library but they don't actualy implement any commands. But if i implement a simple command in it it do not work there either.

So is KeyTip's purely graphical navigation of the Ribbon and do i need to implement my own hotkey listeners using Gestures and other stuff available in WPF to fire the commands?

Comment: Apparently the KeyTip do proc the Button.Click event from looking at the Fluent source code.

Comment: I'm using version 2.0 of Fluent. The OnKeyTipPressed() method calls UIElement.RaiseEvent(). In the new version of fluent(not yet released so i pulled it from version control) this have been replaced with a call to OnClick. So everything is working now. Still unsure why version 2.0 did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug in the 2.0 Release of Fluent Ribbon.

It was fixed in changeset:

7dceb28d2562 on Nov 25 2010 6:46 AM "Command & KeyTip" bug has been fixed.